# Java select files by generated time

Tags: java, ftp

I need to read the file names from ftp server by the specific time they were generated at.

For Example,

```
If I want to get all the files generated between 
2014-04-10 13:00 and 2014-04-10 16:00.
```

File names can be random. Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Eh, I have a solution, though experimental and requiring Java 7, see [here](https://github.com/fge/java7-fs-ftp). You can create a `.newDirectoryStream()` and filter on `BasicFileAttributes`' `.lastModifiedTime()`.

Comment: Otherwise, well, it is doable with any FTP client library. I use Apache commons, but others can do that

Comment: OK that's great... but sadly I am running Java 6, I will upgrade and give it a go. Thanks for you answer

Comment: Well, that will give me some practice so... If the FTP site is publicly available (and accepts anonymous logins), can you give me the address and directory?

Comment: I am sorry, its not public :( Thanks for your help

Comment: OK, if I give you an example on a public site, is that enough to get you started?

Comment: That would be great if you could... Thanks